# Boolean stays the same after incrementing its assigned variable

Tags: java

I don't understand in the example why is `isTrue` still `true` after incrementing `t`.

```
import java.util.*;

public class test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int t = 15;
        boolean isTrue = (t == 15);
        if (isTrue)
        {
            System.out.println("true, t is 15");
        }
        ++t; // t won't be 15 anymore, so isTrue should be false
        if (isTrue)
        {
            System.out.println("not true, t is 16");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't changed `isTrue`.

Comment: You never changed `isTrue` so it's still true, you just incremented the value of the variable `t`

Comment: Java is not a [reactive programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactive_programming). A change in `t` won't be propagated automatically to `isTrue`. You need to assign it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define `isTrue`, you do not set it to `(t == 15)` as a function, but rather to the value of `(t == 15)`, which is `true`. So, in the end, you have: `isTrue = true`. This will stay `true`, even if `t` changes, because the value `true` has now been saved in `isTrue`.

You could define `isTrue` to be a function that takes parameter `t` and returns `t == 15`. Like this:

```
import java.util.*;

public class testowa
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int t = 15;
        if (isTrue(t))
        {
            System.out.println("prawda, wiec wyswietlam");
        }
        ++t;
        if (isTrue(t))
        {
            System.out.println("już nie prawda, bo t=16");
        }
    }

    public static boolean isTrue(int t) 
    {
        return t == 15;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of `isTrue` is never changed. Incrementing `t` doesn't have any effect on `isTrue`.

Answer (score 0):

When you assign the value to `isTrue` the first time, you do not bind that `isTrue` to constantly evaluate `t==15` but you just evaluate it once.

Once the value of `t` changes, you must "manually" evaluate `isTrue` once again, see the example below:

```java
import java.util.*;

public class testowa
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

            int t = 15;
            boolean isTrue = (t==15);
            if (isTrue)
            {
            System.out.println("prawda, wiec wyswietlam");
             }
            ++t;//zwiększam t o 1 więc isTrue w kolejnym if powinno przyjąć wartość false
            isTrue = (t==15);
            if (isTrue)
            {
            System.out.println("już nie prawda, bo t=16");
            }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`isTrue` is just a variable which stores some value. You assigned its value only once, therefore it stays the same throughout the whole program. It's not bound to `t` in any way, meaning if you change `t`, you didn't change `isTrue`. For the expected results, you have to assign `isTrue` again:

```
import java.util.*;

public class testowa
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int t = 15;
        boolean isTrue = (t == 15);
        if (isTrue)
        {
            System.out.println("prawda, wiec wyswietlam");
        }

        ++t; // zwiększam t o 1 więc isTrue w kolejnym if powinno przyjąć wartość false
        isTrue = (t == 15);
        if (isTrue)
        {
            System.out.println("już nie prawda, bo t=16");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you have incremented integer t, which does not have any impact on boolen value isTrue (boolean can only be true or false) and as your code does not loop back to change the boolean value isTrue, isTrue will remain true (even when you have changed the value of integer t)